# Printing literal ' in React Native text object

Tags: text, react-native

I want to print:

Hi, let's do this:

the issue is, it won't work with the "let's" due to the apostrophe.  If I use quotes around this (""), it prints the quotes as well in the view, which I don't want.

How do I do this in React Native?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
<Text>{"Let's"}</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `<Text>{"Hi, let's do this"}</Text>`.

Any time you encounter any difficulty using a Text label, just remember that inside the brackets the rules of JavaScript apply, and so you can do anything in the same way that you would for a JS string.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary work around is to use `&#39;` instead of `'`